Q-learning algorithm to autoscale my kubernetes deployment
Greetings to everyone.
I'm new to Reinforcement learning and i'm trying to create a Q-learning algorithm in order to scale a Kubernetes deployment and get the best reward.
Here's the following code from my .ipynb file
    import numpy as np
import json
import paramiko

# SSH connection details
SSH_CONFIG = {
    'hostname': '****',
    'port': 22,
    'username': '****',
    'password': '****'
}

def connect_ssh():
    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.connect(
        hostname=SSH_CONFIG['hostname'],
        port=SSH_CONFIG['port'],
        username=SSH_CONFIG['username'],
        password=SSH_CONFIG['password'],
        timeout=3
    )
    return ssh_client

def execute_remote_command(ssh_client, command):
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_client.exec_command(command)
    output = stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
    return output

def collect_metrics():
    ssh_client = connect_ssh()
    cpu_query = "curl 'http://localhost:9091/api/v1/query?query=sum(rate(container_cpu_usage_seconds_total[1m]))'"
    memory_query = "curl 'http://localhost:9091/api/v1/query?query=sum(container_memory_usage_bytes)'"

    cpu_output = execute_remote_command(ssh_client, cpu_query)
    memory_output = execute_remote_command(ssh_client, memory_query)

    cpu_data = json.loads(cpu_output)
    memory_data = json.loads(memory_output)

    cpu_usage = float(cpu_data['data']['result'][0]['value'][1])
    memory_usage = float(memory_data['data']['result'][0]['value'][1])

    # Normalize metrics
    cpu_usage = min(cpu_usage / 100, 1.0)
    memory_usage = min(memory_usage / (8 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024), 1.0)  # Assuming 8GB max memory

    metrics = np.array([cpu_usage, memory_usage])
    np.save('metrics.npy', metrics)

    ssh_client.close()

collect_metrics()

import gym
from gym import spaces
import numpy as np

class KubernetesEnv(gym.Env):
    """Custom Gym environment for managing Kubernetes scaling with SSH and Prometheus integration."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(KubernetesEnv, self).__init__()

        # Kubernetes deployment parameters
        self.namespace = "default"
        self.deployment_name = "nginx-deployment"
        self.min_replicas = 1
        self.max_replicas = 10
        self.current_replicas = 3

        # Define action space and observation space
        self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(3)  # 0 = scale down, 1 = no change, 2 = scale up
        self.observation_space = spaces.Box(low=0, high=1, shape=(2,), dtype=np.float32)  # CPU and memory usage

    def get_metrics(self):
        """Fetch CPU and memory usage from the .npy file."""
        metrics = np.load('metrics.npy')
        return metrics

    def scale_deployment(self, action):
        """Scale Kubernetes deployment based on the action."""
        if action == 0:  # Scale down
            self.current_replicas = max(self.min_replicas, self.current_replicas - 1)
        elif action == 2:  # Scale up
            self.current_replicas = min(self.max_replicas, self.current_replicas + 1)

        print(f"Scaling deployment {self.deployment_name} to {self.current_replicas} replicas.")

    def step(self, action):
        """Execute one time step within the environment."""
        self.scale_deployment(action)
        state = self.get_metrics()

        # Apply the refined reward system
        cpu, memory = state
        reward = -0.1  # Small penalty for each step to encourage efficiency

        # Reward for optimal range
        if 0.4 <= cpu <= 0.6 and 0.4 <= memory <= 0.6:
            reward += 2  # Increased reward for optimal range
        elif cpu < 0.4 or memory < 0.4:
            reward -= 1  # Increased penalty for under-utilization
        elif cpu > 0.6 or memory > 0.6:
            reward -= 1.5  # Increased penalty for over-utilization

        # Additional reward for stability
        if self.current_replicas == 3:
            reward += 0.5  # Reward for maintaining a stable state

        done = False  # This environment does not have a terminal state
        info = {"replicas": self.current_replicas}

        return state, reward, done, info

    def reset(self):
        """Reset the environment to its initial state."""
        self.current_replicas = 3  # Starting with 3 replicas
        return self.get_metrics()

    def render(self, mode='human'):
        """Render the environment status."""
        print(f"Current replicas: {self.current_replicas}")

    def close(self):
        """Cleanup the environment."""
        pass
    class QLearningAgent:
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size, learning_rate=0.05, discount_factor=0.9, exploration_rate=1.0, exploration_decay=0.999, min_exploration_rate=0.01):
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.learning_rate = learning_rate
        self.discount_factor = discount_factor
        self.exploration_rate = exploration_rate
        self.exploration_decay = exploration_decay
        self.min_exploration_rate = min_exploration_rate
        self.q_table = np.zeros((5, 5, action_size))  # Reduced to 5 discrete states for CPU and memory

    def choose_action(self, state):
        """Choose an action based on the current state using the epsilon-greedy strategy."""
        state_idx = self.discretize_state(state)
        if np.random.rand() <= self.exploration_rate:
            return random.choice(range(self.action_size))  # Explore
        return np.argmax(self.q_table[state_idx])  # Exploit

    def learn(self, state, action, reward, next_state):
        """Update the Q-table based on the experience."""
        state_idx = self.discretize_state(state)
        next_state_idx = self.discretize_state(next_state)
        best_next_action = np.argmax(self.q_table[next_state_idx])
        td_target = reward + self.discount_factor * self.q_table[next_state_idx][best_next_action]
        td_error = td_target - self.q_table[state_idx][action]
        self.q_table[state_idx][action] += self.learning_rate * td_error

    def discretize_state(self, state):
        """Discretize the continuous state for the Q-table."""
        cpu, memory = state
        cpu_idx = min(int(cpu * 5), 4)  # 5 discrete states for CPU
        memory_idx = min(int(memory * 5), 4)  # 5 discrete states for Memory
        return (cpu_idx, memory_idx)
    def train_agent(env, agent, num_episodes, max_steps_per_episode):
    """Train the Q-learning agent."""
    rewards_per_episode = []

    for episode in range(num_episodes):
        state = env.reset()  # Reset the environment and get initial state
        total_reward = 0

        for step in range(max_steps_per_episode):
            action = agent.choose_action(state)  # Choose action
            next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)  # Step the environment
            agent.learn(state, action, reward, next_state)  # Update Q-table

            state = next_state  # Transition to the new state
            total_reward += reward

            # Print the reward for each step
            print(f"Episode {episode}, Step {step} - Reward: {reward}")

            if reward == 1.5:  # End episode early if in optimal state
                break

        rewards_per_episode.append(total_reward)
        agent.exploration_rate = max(agent.min_exploration_rate, agent.exploration_rate * agent.exploration_decay)  # Decay exploration rate

        # Print the total reward for each episode
        print(f"Episode {episode} - Total reward: {total_reward}")

    print("Training complete.")
    return rewards_per_episode

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Initialize Kubernetes environment
    env = KubernetesEnv()

    # Initialize Q-learning agent
    agent = QLearningAgent(state_size=env.observation_space.shape[0], action_size=env.action_space.n)

    # Train the agent
    num_episodes = 500  # Adjusted for faster training
    max_steps_per_episode = 50  # Adjusted for faster training
    rewards = train_agent(env, agent, num_episodes, max_steps_per_episode)

    # Close the environment after training
    env.close()

However, the desired result is not what i expected.
Here's an example output:
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 1 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 24 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 1 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 25 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 1 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 26 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 2 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 27 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 2 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 28 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 3 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 29 - Reward: -0.6000000000000001
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 4 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 30 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 5 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 31 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 6 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 32 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 7 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 33 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 8 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 34 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 8 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 35 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 8 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 36 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 9 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 37 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 10 replicas.
Episode 191, Step 38 - Reward: -1.1
Scaling deployment nginx-deployment to 10 replicas.

if i change the learning_rate i don't get any different results...
Can anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?
Thank you in advance
